# Youtube browser based upload

Tags: browser, upload, youtube

We have set up an upload page on a client's site to upload videos to YouTube using the browser based upload rather than direct upload.

We have run some test uploads for videos around 500Mb in size which have uploaded fine, but we had a shot at a much large one - 1.9Gb - and that failed.

The only error we could see was in the return URL which ended "status=400&error=TOKEN_EXPIRED".

Now, the videos do take a long time to upload.  On average a 400Mb video takes just under 2 hours, so we reckoned on a 1.9Gb video to take getting on for 10 hours.

Could the issue be that the token which Youtube returns is only valid for a certain period of time, and because of the length of time taken to upload the 1.9Gb files, it simply expired?

I can't find any anwser to this on the Google forum and in any case that forum is now closed to new posts.

If anyone can shed some light on this we would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

How long was the upload going for when you got this token?
Youtube did have a token timeout at like 4.5hours, not sure if they still do or not.

Comment: Difficult to say.  Because of the estimated upload time, we just left it running overnight.  It interesting that you say that they used to have a token timeout.  What we are doing now is to upload some files,increasing the size incrementally to see if there is a cut-off point.  We will look out at 4.5 hours. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I mean that was back when the time limit on videos were like 10mins. Which obviously they now have no time limit on videos, but I assume there would still be a cut off point even if it sounds a bad idea in the users point of view.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  Just uploaded a 700Mb file successfully, so progress of a kind :-)

Comment: Okay cool, if the file gets too big, then perhaps spilt the file into parts (what most users do). If you do not come across a time limit and it all works fine, then perhaps it was just a upload error which sometimes happens due to connections being made over a long period of time and perhaps was a one off, I say this because sometimes if theres a drop in connection on either side it sometimes drops the upload altoghether. Sorry I can't give a straight answer but theres so many things that could cause the upload to stop. Help I helped :)

Comment: Philip, I think you may be right about the upload error.  Just completed a 1.1Gb upload with no problems.  Took 3.5 hours.  All we need to do is to figure some sort of progress indicator.  Can't be done with a straight POST, so will have to look at an alternative handler.  Anyway, thanks for your input.  Much appreciated! :-)